Feeling this proof that $\log_b(n)$ is $O(n)$, where b is any positive real number $\neq 2$, has an error.

From Rosen's Discrete Math textbook, I feel the part of the proof where they say
$$\log_b n = \frac{\log_2 n}{\log_2 b} < \frac{n}{\log_2 b}$$ where $b$ is any positive number not equal to $2$ is wrong.
It seems the author tried to apply the inequality $\log_2 n < n$ here, but if $0 < b < 1$, then $\log_2 b < 0$, meaning $\frac{1}{\log_2 b} < 0$, hence shouldn't
$$\frac{\log_2 n}{\log_2 b} > \frac{n}{\log_2 b}?$$ Kindly let me know

$\log_2 b$ is negative, when $0<b<1$.

Sorry yes my bad will put in edit! Question still holds though.

You're right, the given proof only works for $b>1$. I'd guess the author had $b$ integer in mind. (It's never really specified what $b$ is)

@anankElpis yes I just realized this too. They're appendix for logarithms defines the base to be > 1. Hence the Big-O relation makes sense. But what's bugging me is figuring out which notation to use -- Big-, Big-Ω, or Big-Θ notations -- in describing the relation between $log_b{n}$ and $n$ if 0 < b < 1.

Note that $\log_bn=-\log_{1/b}n$, hence in particular $|\log_bn|=|\log_{1/b}n|$.
